# Barcode reader last digit UPC-A

Tags: barcode

is it possible to have my reader read the last digit of UPC-A (CheckSum) and not write it.
(BY config)

Let's say it reads 123456789012 (2 is the checksum)

and then it writes 12345678901 without the checksum.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. I was using the wrong manual, the readers do have configurations to show the checksum or not.

Answer (score 0):

A Barcode Scanner is an input device....no different than a mouse or keyboard.
The final output is based upon whatever function is determined by your software.

The way that UPC barcodes work is, the barcode graphic is scanned, the bars are converted back to numbers and a database query is done comparing the 12-digit number represented by the bars against the 12 digit number in the database. When that item is found, the next function of the software is performed (price look-up, inventory change, etc.)

If you have a different need, you would have to write your software code to perform a different function which could be writing the first 11 digits.